# angularjs, enter on input field dont submit

Tags: javascript, html, .net, angularjs, forms

I got a MVC form, and I'm creating a keyword selector as a angular directive, which works fine. But I can't seem to figure out how i can prevent the 'enter' event to submit the form ?

I want to be able to write some text in the input field, press enter, and then the text which the user wrote will be shown underneath as a keyword, but instead of doing this, the form submits.

How can I prevent the submittion of the form on enter?
It is created with normal html input fields created in the directive.

Any ideas ?

(accurately much like how the tags section here on stackoverflow works)

Comment: cant u use textarea instead of text box :)

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: mhh, i thought of the option. But just thought that i should use the proper one, which for me is input.. But that would solve it, yes :)

Comment: The form must submit on Enter. You problem is not here, but how to handle the submission. Post your code if you want help, otherwise it's hard to do anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple noenter directive:

```
app.directive('noenter',function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.on('keypress', function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
          return false;

      }
      return true;
    })
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" noenter />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<form ng-submit="return false;">
```